# Unrecognizable device on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I want to run my code on the phone. But Android does not recognize my device. I also did the connection assistant.
But the following error is given. please guide me.
[image]

[image]

Comment: is developer mode active on device ?

Comment: Make sure developer options is turned on and usb debugging too

Comment: Activate Developer mode: Settings -> about -> tap build 5 times. Developer mode will appear and toggle the USB Debugging

Comment: There is a good tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/

Comment: Not only does the device not be detected, but the built-in AVD is also not detected.

Comment: Yes. developer mode is active.

Comment: try resetting your ADB server by running `adb kill-server` and then `adb connect`. Also make sure that the cable you're using allows data transfer and it's not only for charging

Comment: When I want to run, this message will be received:

Comment: Why does not AVD run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Needed informations

- Is `ADB` installed with Android Studio, or have you got external tool?
- Is there a generic Android USB Device driver installed? It's provided with Android Studio, and should be obtained with SDK Tools.

#### Possible solution

- If even AVD cannot be recognized, it could be fault of built-in ADB server. I would recommend installing ADB as an external program, e.g. from [here (ClockworkMod page)](https://adb.clockworkmod.com).
- After installation, reboot PC and plug your phone in. If phone is visible, check for availability via `adb devices` command from CMD/terminal. **Don't launch Android Studio yet**, as it has its own instance of ADB server and you wouldn't be able to launch second one from console.
- If phone is visible, use `adb kill-server` command to finish the console instance, and launch Android Studio. Everything should be detected, if not - you really should submit that bug...
- If phone is not visible all the time after issuing `adb devices`, there is a chance that not all drivers are installed. Check ASUS for drivers, if they were installed automatically - install them manually.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PdaNet+](http://pdanet.co/a/)

Install both the desktop client and the corresponding android application from the google play store. Once you plug in your device it will prompt you that your device has been connected and adb should recognise it.